# How to move an application's dialog box from a disconnected monitor to the main

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, display

I have a problem similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/98032/moving-a-window-from-a-disconnected-monitor-to-connected-monitor-on-vista), where I have a dialog box (several, actually) that opens on a disconnected monitor.  Since the dialog box does not have an entry on the taskbar, I cannot invoke the "move" command.  Short of reconnecting the monitor, is there any other way to get the dialog boxes back to my main monitor?  I'm using Windows XP, SP2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Use Alt-Tab to make the app/dialog active.
2. Press Alt-Space, followed by the 'm' key (in english OS - *M*ove, different letter in other languages).
3. Hold the left arrow for a second.
4. Move your mouse (without pressing any mouse buttons) until you see it.
5. Press `enter` when you have it where you want. (Left click works as well.)

If the dialog is modal (like an open file dialog), it should get focus when the main app is selected, even if it doesn't have an entry on the taskbar. The Alt-Space followed by 'm' selects the move option on the window.

Comment: Whoo-hoo!  Awesome, except that (for me) for step 5 hitting enter does work, but right-click doesn't.  Anyway, solved!  Thanks!

Comment: You can press Enter or *left* click to drop the window.

Comment: I've also seen this happen many times. I knew the fix already, but it blows me away that such a glaring omission could be ignored between Win XP, Vista, Me, and 7. Why bring a window up on a screen that doesn't exist? Don't Microsoft's programmers actually _use_ windows? Multiple monitors have been supported in Windows for, what, 15 years? </rant>

Comment: does not works for me on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your computer still thinks the external monitor is attached, because when there is only 1 display, all dialogs should automatically be moved to that display. I would check in your display properties to make sure that your remaining monitor is the only one set up, and that the other one is indeed disconnected.

Comment: I would think it would work that way too; that was the first thing I checked.  Thanks though.

Comment: Does the problem persist even after a reboot?

Answer (score 0):

**Options include:**

- Move your main monitor to the second port, move them all back, then reattach.
- You can also disable the second display completely in display properties

  - Right click desktop
  - properties
  - settings
  - Dropdown for display
  - Select second display and uncheck "extend my desktop..."

Comment: Yes, I actually ensured that "extend my desktop" was unchecked already, thanks.

Comment: @Aerik - Sorry!