# How to move a Modeless dialog that is on a disconnected monitor

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors

Similar to the following questions (but different):

- [Moving a window from a disconnected monitor to connected monitor on Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/98032/moving-a-window-from-a-disconnected-monitor-to-connected-monitor-on-vista)
- [How to move an application's dialog box from a disconnected monitor to the main](https://superuser.com/questions/187176/how-to-move-an-applications-dialog-box-from-a-disconnected-monitor-to-the-main)

I have an application that opens a modeless dialog (no entry in taskbar), but that dialog opens on a monitor that is not connected at the moment.

How can I move this modeless dialog to my current monitor?

**Update**

I had to close the application, then re-open it, and then both suggestions by @torbengb and @Xantec worked.
Thanks!

Comment: bummer, [torbengb](http://superuser.com/questions/215328/how-to-move-a-modeless-dialog-that-is-on-a-disconnected-monitor/215352#215352) beat me by 21 seconds

Comment: If the window doesn't have focus, can you alt-tab to select it? If yes, then the answers given will help you.

Comment: Xantec: Glad to be the one to be ahead for a change :-)

Comment: @torbengb alt-tab is not selecting it.  :(

Comment: glad to hear you got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, you can always get to the window menu using the keyboard:

1. Press `Alt+Space` then `Enter` which selects the first menu entry, *Move*.
2. Then use the arrow keys to move the dialog.
3. If the window is outside your visible viewport, then the dialog should jump into sight at the first arrow-keypress. If it doesn't then I hope you can remember to what side the unconnected monitor was and press the arrow key for the opposite direction.

Comment: In my case the Alt+Space brings up the system menu for the parent application, not the modeless dialog.  I can use Spy++ to verify that the window is created, but I can't find a way to move it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can be reasonably sure that the dialog has focus you can try ALT+Space then M and use the arrow keys to move it. when you have it where you want it press Enter.

Comment: In my case the Alt+Space brings up the system menu for the parent application, not the modeless dialog. I can use Spy++ to verify that the window is created, but I can't find a way to move it.