# How do I change Windows XP Primary monitor when I can only access the secondary?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors

I was logged in by a remote screen interface, and a window had opened on the secondary monitor.  I managed to change the primary monitor through display settings.  I can see the desired window, but now I can't switch my primary monitor - task manager and display settings are open on primary, which also has the start menu.

Is there some other method to switch the monitors, or move the display settings window?

Comment: Related and possible dupe: http://superuser.com/q/187176

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this click... Alt-Tab to select the *Display Settings*. Then push [ALT]+[SPACE BAR], to open the menu with the options to move, size, close, and etc. Push [M], this will select *Move* and it will also move your mouse to the perfect spot. After pushing the [M] key, click and hold then drag the window to your secondary screen.

<strike>If you Alt-Tab and selected the wrong window, then try it over and over until you select the correct one.</strike>  To make sure you select the *Display Settings* windows on first time... Right click the background and select display properties. This will bring the window to front as the **active window** <strike>or open the display property window (hidden away on the primary screen) if it wasnt</strike>. Once you have done this then follow the steps above except for the first (Alt-Tab) step.

*Good Luck :P*