# How to keep the taskbar (and or or open windows) off-screen?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

So it's the exact opposite to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/98032/moving-a-window-from-a-disconnected-monitor-to-connected-monitor-on-vista).

---

I have 2 desktops **C** and **D**, 2 screens *M* and *N*, respectively.

*M* is directly connected to **C** as the primary screen while *N* is connected to both **C** and **D** through a physical switch:

> desktops　　　　screens
>
> **C** ──────── *M* (primary for **C**)
>
> ├──(switch)── *N*
>
> **D**

I use **C** + *M* + *N* combination most of the time so I moved **C**'s taskbar to the secondary screen *N* for example.

The problem is that when I switch in order to temporarily use **D**, i.e. *N* gets disconnected from **C**, then the disconnection is immediately caught by Windows (blink) and it moves everything from *N* to *M*.

I want them not displayed on *M*, but to stay off the screen.

I can think of 2 options without how-to:

1. Disable such "automagic detection" and manually detect at [Settings] - [System] - [Display] if needed
2. Lie to Windows somehow that the screen *N* is working well so no relocation is needed

**C** is using a GeForce GTX so Nvidia specific solutions are fine, too.

Comment: Welcome to Windows. This is unfortunately not possible. Because windows no longer detects the screen, the driver using plug and play is uninstalled at disconnect, which automatically moves all windows to the left. There is software that can be used to control the position, but I don't know any free software. I use ActualTools Window Manager, but even that program really struggles when a screen is uninstalled.

Comment: You may be able to buy a different KVM switch that keeps sending data to windows to keep the screen alive. That might be your only option. Or maybe not make that screen go through the switch, but only to the pc, so its always active.

Comment: Thanks @LPChip. You already gave a complete "answer" though!

Comment: Heh, I hadn't realized. I posted this as an answer, so you can mark it as anwersed. Others will know you no longer need help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Windows. This is unfortunately not possible. Because windows no longer detects the screen, the driver using plug and play is uninstalled at disconnect, which automatically moves all windows to the left. There is software that can be used to control the position, but I don't know any free software. I use ActualTools Window Manager, but even that program really struggles when a screen is uninstalled.

You may be able to buy a different KVM switch that keeps sending data to windows to keep the screen alive. That might be your only option. Or maybe not make that screen go through the switch, but only to the pc, so its always active.