# windows 10, reserve space for disconnected displays or otherwise disable automatic window repositioning

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, window, display-settings

Unlike every other kvm I've ever used, my new one reports, to the previously displayed computer, that the monitors are being disconnected when switching views, so all my windows get rearranged on my Windows 10 laptop. I want to disable this "feature" of moving all windows to the remaining display (built-in) so I don't have to rearrange them every time I switch back. This is effectively the opposite problem as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/98032/moving-a-window-from-a-disconnected-monitor-to-connected-monitor-on-vista/1237607#1237607).

Side note: this problem does not occur on my ubuntu desktop, which preserves window positions even when no monitor can display.

Edit: while this could be considered a problem with my kvm, I doubt their support will be able to do much about it other than offer a partial refund, seeing as it is a dedicated hardware device with limited configurability. However, the potential software fix for this issue would not only be applicable to this issue but others who might want to be able to turn off, sleep, or unplug a monitor without needing to rearrange their desktops.

Edit 2: dear future reader, this appears to be a lost cause. My company's IT has provided me with a license for DisplayFusion to work around this windows 10 issue. He has also pointed me to a video showing off a fix for it in windows 11 as if it were a feature (as if catching up to something linux has had for a decade is praise-worthy). If you are finding this *before* purchasing a kvm, I encourage you to pay the extra few $s for a hdmi kvm and adapters to dp if needed. The dp standard is obviously flawed.

Comment: What did their product support say when you asked them about this issue?

Comment: "Your ticket has been created. Please use the following ticket number when referencing this issue in the future..." Nothing from a human yet.