# Move all windows to primary display when disconnecting monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11

Is there a way to configure Windows 11 to move all windows back to the primary display when I disconnect an external monitor?

I use my laptop at home and at work, with two different external monitors. It's a huge pain to have to use the old workaround from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/98032/moving-a-window-from-a-disconnected-monitor-to-connected-monitor-on-vista) every time I connect a different monitor. The easiest solution would be to have any windows on that external monitor revert to the primary display (laptop screen) when I disconnect the monitor.

Is this possible? Or some simpler "bulk move everything to primary" option?

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to move windows to my primary display

You can use Nirsoft MultiMonitorTool:

> MultiMonitorTool is a small tool that allows you to do some actions related to working with multiple monitors. With MultiMonitorTool, you can disable/enable monitors, set the primary monitor, save and load the configuration of all monitors, and **move windows from one monitor to another**. You can do these actions from the user interface or from command-line, without displaying user interface.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [Enable/disable/configure multiple monitors on Windows](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)